# ConvertBack is not called

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, converters

I'm trying to write a universal control in which I can pass different data models (all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`) with a converter. The data is passed in the control without problems and is displayed correctly (some of it also uses `IMultivalueConverts`, which work flawlessly). Although the data is modified, the `IMultiValueConverter` of the MainControl is not called.

The universal control should just show rectangles calculated from coordinates in an ObservableCollection.

I put DebugConverters on all bindings, and everything seems to be updated except the ConvertBack to the top. The SourceUpdate from the ListBox is also called.

I tried this converter with different NotifyOn...Updated, Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger, I always see the values changing in the control, but never the ConvertBack of the Main Control.

The partial data template used (Updates are done correctly), all the DegreeTo... converters are called both ways

```xml
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RectangleWithLabel">
            <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="True">
                <Rectangle x:Name="RectangleROI" MouseLeftButtonDown="myCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" >
                    <!--
                    <Rectangle.Visibility>
                        <Binding Path="ROI" Converter="{StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Visibility>
                    -->
                    <Canvas.Left>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DegreeToScreenPixelConverterH}" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                            <Binding Path="ROI.Begin.PosH" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.UsedCoordinateSystem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Canvas.Left>
                    <Canvas.Top>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DegreeToScreenPixelConverterV}"  Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding Path="ROI.Begin.PosV" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"   NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.UsedCoordinateSystem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Canvas.Top>
                    <Rectangle.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DegreeToScreenPixelWidthConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding Path="ROI.Begin.PosH" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            <Binding Path="ROI.End.PosH" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"   NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.UsedCoordinateSystem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Rectangle.Width>
                    <Rectangle.Height>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DegreeToScreenPixelHeightConverter}"  Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding Path="ROI.Begin.PosV" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"   NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                            <Binding Path="ROI.End.PosV" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"   NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.UsedCoordinateSystem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Rectangle.Height>
                    <Rectangle.Fill>#33FF0000</Rectangle.Fill>
                    <Rectangle.Stroke>#FF00FF00</Rectangle.Stroke>
                    <Rectangle.IsHitTestVisible>true</Rectangle.IsHitTestVisible>
                </Rectangle>
```

The List View containing all the data:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"   x:Name="listBox" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=ImageControl, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ImageControl, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RectangleWithLabel}" MouseMove="ListBox_MouseMove" DataContextChanged="ListBox_DataContextChanged" SourceUpdated="ListBox_SourceUpdated" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" TargetUpdated="ListBox_TargetUpdated"  />
```

The call to the ImageViewer from the parent, here the converter is called on the way to the ImageViewer, but the ConvertBack is never called:

```xml
        <common:ImageViewer x:Name="ctrlImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <common:ImageViewer.DataContext>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterWhichIsOnlyCalledOneWay}" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding Path="." UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnSourceUpdated="True" NotifyOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </common:ImageViewer.DataContext>
        </common:ImageViewer>
```

How can I get the `ConvertBack` to be called?

EDIT:

I made an overview of the controls and the converters. I think I was wrong, that the ConvertBack should be called, everything is updating, even without the big converter. But I'm still stuck when adding some elements to the `ObservableCollection`. When I add some values, the values appear in the DataContext of the MainWindow. But the Converter is not triggered. When I add the `Observable.Count` as Binding to the Big Converter, the update is triggered, but all bindings are lost.

Changes from the original code were: Changing all internal variables to `DependencyProperties`, this made updates reliable for the single entries in the `ObservableCollection`.

[Overview of the GUI and the used converters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJR2X.png)

Comment: Where do you change the canvas left and top or the rectangle width and height properties?

Comment: The canvas left and right is saved in the ViewModel, its in ROI.Begin.PosH and .PosV. The width are calculated over DegreeToScreenPixelHeightConverter or ..Width... converter, this is working flawlessly. Also the update is reflected int the SourceUpdate of the ListBox.

Comment: ConvertBack is called only if the bound value is somehow modified by the bound control outside viewmodel right? When is canvas width and top value is changed other than in view model?

Comment: The canvas size is only used internall in the control, it is never passed outside. Only ROI.[Begin|End].[PosH|PosV] is used in the view model, although it gets information from the View model for the Coordinate System (which is just linear)

Comment: So, when and why do you expect convertback to be called? That's not clear in your question.

Comment: Sorry, if it awas not clear, the ConvertBack should be called whenever I modify the rectangle by mouse (There is an Adorner Layer to do this).

Comment: OK; I'm now pretty sure, that the Binding on the control gets lost somehow: If I read back the binding BindingExpression binding = ctrlImage.GetBindingExpression(ImageViewer.DataContextProperty); is null. If I set the binding manually, the update happens, but after that, the binding is null again. I'll try to fire an event whenever one of the controls modifies the data and then I renew the binding in the main again...

Comment: If you assign a value manually to a property which is bound, binding will be removed and the value will be set directly.

Comment: @MatJ I know, but the binding is gone after all controls are displayed, and before anything was changed. I added a button in the parent window and read out the bindings in this. Can it be, that the converter destroys the binding? Because at first, the original data is assigned to the data context and after that, the data from the result of the converter is assigned...

Comment: Converter cannot remove binding, but when you resize, how do you set the value back? Is it from any event? Will the event fire on initial load, Is it setting it directly there?

Comment: OK, as a workaround, I fire an event in on Source Updated (from Image to Text representation and vice versa):
`private void Grid_SourceUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
{ OnDataChanged(new EventArgs() { });}`
and I renew the binding in the parent control:`Binding myBinding = new Binding("Data");myBinding.Source = this;myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;ctrlText.SetBinding(ImageViewer.DataContextProperty, myBinding);}`. This works, but is not very nice!

Comment: Resizing is just from an Object impleemting INotifyPropertyChanged. But it is only operating with value types (doubles) and not with reference types like the other converter. So maybe there is some other way this is handled?

Comment: No, I mean who and how does `Rectangle.Width` is set? Is it set to `Rectangle.Width` property directly anywhere? if yes, there is your problem. If not, you don't need `convertback` call at all right?

Comment: It is set in the Adorner handler:
`void HandleBottomLeft(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs args)
{
FrameworkElement adornedElement = AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;
Thumb hitThumb = sender as Thumb;
adornedElement.Height = Math.Max(args.VerticalChange + adornedElement.Height, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Height);
width_old = adornedElement.Width;
width_new = Math.Max(adornedElement.Width - args.HorizontalChange, hitThumb.DesiredSize.Width);
left_old = Canvas.GetLeft(adornedElement);
adornedElement.Width = width_new;
Canvas.SetLeft(adornedElement, left_old - (width_new - width_old));
}`

Comment: I left out some stuff (e.g. vars are declared as double) out to make it fit in the comment...

Comment: You can add to your question, comments are not for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time to answer the question myself:

I was wrong when assuming that a changes travels down throught the converter when there is a direct connection between two elements.

So if I have an element (just consider it as a leave of a tree) in a deeply nested and it is once displayed once through a converter (which changes **some** other objects) and the same time without a converter, the element is updated without calling the converter. WPF is so clever to see that the value is the same and does not pipe the change through the converter up and down.